# Confusion about Artist place in matplotlib hierarchy

Tags: python, matplotlib

In this period I am working with matplotlib. I studied many examples, and was able to modify it to suit several of my needs. But I would like to better understand the general structure of the library. For this reason, apart reading a lot of tutorials on the web, I also purchased the ebook "Matplotlib for Python Developers", by Tosi. While it is full of good examples, I still don't fully grasp the relationships between all the different levels.

The book clearly explains that matplotlib has 3 main "modes":

1) pylab, to work similarly to Matlab

2) pyplot, to work in a procedural way

3) the full OO system

Concerning the objects of the OO system, the book lists 3 levels:

1) FigureCanvas, the container class for the Figure instance

2) Figure, the container for Axes instances

3) Axes, the areas that hold the basic elements (lines, points, text...)

The problem is that, by reading the official documentation, I also encountered the notions of Backends and Artists. While I understand the basic logic of them, I am quite confused about their role respect to the previous classifications. In particular, are the Artists in an intermediate level between the FigureCanvas and the Figure, or is that hierarchy not suitable in this case?

I would be grateful to receive some clarifications, eventually also referring to other documentation I could have missed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not like those layers

- `pylab` : massive namespace dump that pulls in everything from `pyplot` and `numpy`.  It is not a 'layer' so much as a very cluttered name space.
- `pyplot` : state-machine based layer (it knows what your 'current axes' and 'current figure' are and applies the functions to *that* axes/figure.  You should use this *only* when you are playing around in an interactive terminal (other than `plt.subplots` or `plt.figure` for setting up the figure/axes objects).  Making a distiction between this layer and `pylab` is dumb. *This* is the layer that makes it 'like MATLAB'
- the OO layer : which is what you should use in all of your scripts

`Figure`s are the top level container objects.  They can contain `Axes` objects and `Artist` objects (technically `Axes` *are* `Artists`, but it is useful for pedagogical reasons to distinguish between the `Axes` objects in a figure and the other artists (such as `text` objects) that are in the `Figure`, but not associated with an `Axes`) and know about the `Canvas` object.  Each `Axes` can contain more `Artists` objects.  The `Artists` are the useful things you want to put on your graph (lines, text, images, etc).  `Artists` know how to draw themselves on a `Canvas`.  When you call `fig.savefig` (or render the figure to the screen) the `Figure` object loops over all of it's children and tell them to draw them selves on to it's `Canvas`.

The different `Backends` provide implementations of the `Canvas` objects, hence the same figure can be rendered to a raster or vector graphic by just changing the `Canvas` object that is being used.

Unless you want to write a new backend, many of these details are not important and the fact that matplotlib hides them from you is why it is useful.

If the book couldn't get this correct, I would take everything it says with grain of salt.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination.
However I stiil have several doubts.
In the official matplotlib tutorial, they say that the 3 API layers are:1) FigureCanvas 2) Renderer 3) Artist, and there are 2 types of Artists: primitives and containers. Some of the containers are Figure and Axes. This seems a bit in contradiction with your description, or am I missing something?

Comment: The renderers are the interface layer between the canvas and the `Artists`. Unless you want to dive really deep, the `FigureCanvas` objects take care of setting up their own renderers. I don't see any contradiction, the above description is the practical explanation of what you need to know to use mpl.  If you want to _write_ a new backend that is a different matter.

Comment: I thank you for the clarifications. The only point of your first post that I think is not correct is:"They can contain Axes objects and Artist objects and know about the Canvas object". Actually, if I now understand correctly, Axes are Artist objects, in particular of the type container. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, `Axes` are `Artists` (because everything that can draw it self to the canvas is an `Artist`), but it is better to think about `Figure` objects as containing `Axes` (which then contain the rest of your useful artists) and then some other `Artist` objects (ex a text object for the figure title).

Comment: Edited text to make this (subtle) point, thank you for catching my sloppiness.